# activity logging of a python file to a log module

Tags: python, python-logging

I want a python file to run as usual how it runs. But, I want to log the activities going on in the python file in a log file.How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit slow, but the easiest way would probably be:

```
$ python -m trace --trace your_file.py > trace.log
```

There's other ways too, but this is a built-in one that's rather detailed using the [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) module.

Assuming I understand your question, another option would be to visualize what it's doing which usually is a bit more meaningful.
You can do that with a tool called [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer):

```
$ viztracer your_module.py
```

You can then use visualization tools to render the result in a meaningful way, such as https://ui.perfetto.dev/

[image]